# Ajax TabContainer intermittently dissapears on Postback

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I am developing a GIS web app (mapping) in C# ASP.net.

I have an Ajax TabContainer housing several TabPanels with a table. The table contains other content such as the map window, scale bar etc (all from the ESRI WebAdf toolkit).

Here's a slimmed down version of my table without the other content...

```
<table id="MainTable>

<tr>
<td>
   <ajax:TabContainer runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" id="TabContainer"  CssClass="ajax__tab_xp">  

    <ajax:TabPanel runat="server" HeaderText="Online Mapping Service" ID="TabPanel1">

</ajax:TabPanel>

<ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel2" runat="server" HeaderText="Postcode">


    </ajax:TabPanel>

    <ajax:TabPanel ID="TabPanel3" runat="server" HeaderText="Coordinates">
        <ContentTemplate>                                      



  </ajax:TabPanel>

   </ajax:TabContainer> 

  </td>
  </tr>

  </table>
```

On Postback at runtime my Tabcontainer sometimes dissapears. This issue is not browser specific.

So far I have tried with no success to...

1. Set Z-Index with Relative positioning for the TabContainer
2. Include a JQuery script to 'show' the TabContainer...

   ```
       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#TabContainer").show();

       });

      </script>
   ```

Is there some C# I can include in the code behind along the lines of?...

```
Public void page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   TabContainer.show()
}
```

Fairly new to programming and trying to figure out how to 'always show' or 'always ontop' the TabContainer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorted this. There was an issue with the AJAX Toolkit not posting back client side...

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        // Solution to sys.invalidoperationexception bug
        Sys.Application.initialize = function Sys$_Application$initialize() {
            if (!this._initialized && !this._initializing) {
                this._initializing = true;
                var loadMethodSet = false;
                var initializeDelegate = Function.createDelegate(this, this._doInitialize);
                if (document.addEventListener) {
                    loadMethodSet = true;
                    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", initializeDelegate, false);
                }
                if (/WebKit/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
                    loadMethodSet = true;
                    this._load_timer = setInterval(function() {
                        if (/loaded|complete/.test(document.readyState)) {
                            initializeDelegate();
                        }
                    }, 10);
                }
                else {
                    /*@cc_on@*/
                    /*@if (@_win32)
                    loadMethodSet = true;
                    document.write("<script id=__ie_onload defer src=BLOCKED SCRIPTvoid(0)><\/scr" + "ipt>");
                    var deferScript = document.getElementById("__ie_onload");
                    if (deferScript) {
                        deferScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if (this.readyState == "complete") {
                                initializeDelegate();
                            }
                        };
                    }
                    /*@end@*/
                }

                // only if no other method will execute initializeDelegate is
                // it wired to the window's load method.
                if (!loadMethodSet) {
                    $addHandler(window, "load", initializeDelegate);
                }
            }
        }
        Sys.Application._doInitialize = function Sys$_Application$_doInitialize() {
            if (this._load_timer !== null) {
                clearInterval(this._load_timer);
                this._load_timer = null;
            }

            Sys._Application.callBaseMethod(this, 'initialize');

            var handler = this.get_events().getHandler("init");
            if (handler) {
                this.beginCreateComponents();
                handler(this, Sys.EventArgs.Empty);
                this.endCreateComponents();
            }
            this.raiseLoad();
            this._initializing = false;
        }

        Sys.Application._loadHandler = function Sys$_Application$_loadHandler() {
            if (this._loadHandlerDelegate) {
                Sys.UI.DomEvent.removeHandler(window, "load",
                  this._loadHandlerDelegate);
                this._loadHandlerDelegate = null;
            }
            this._initializing = true;
            this._doInitialize();
        }         

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is due to the fact that you cleaned your code before posting it here but you are missing  tags.

The code on your aspx should look like this :

```
<AjaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer" runat="server">
    <AjaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            Your asp/html code goes here
        </ContentTemplate>
    </AjaxToolkit:TabPanel>
 </AjaxToolkit:TabContainer>
```

Comment: Yes, I have just cleaned it as not to post the whole table. The table and TabContainer HTML is correct and runs, it's just the dissapearing issue that's affecting it.

Comment: Anyone have an idea on this? It's driving me crazy!